# calculating minimum size needed to contain dialog

Tags: winapi, dialog, scroll, getsystemmetrics

I want to compute the minimum size both vertical and horizontal that will contain a dialog.
I used GetClientRect to determine the width and height.  Then for the width when a vertical scroll bar is needed I added GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXVSCROLL) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZEFRAME) but I seem to come up a few pixels short.

What GetSysMetrics do I need to take into account for both the horizontal and vertical dimensions with and without scroll bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for window borders and other non-client area space.  The easiest way to do this is use `AdjustWindowRect()` or `AdjustWindowRectEx()`. However, you will still need to handle the scroll bars yourself:

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The AdjustWindowRectEx function does not take the WS_VSCROLL or WS_HSCROLL styles into account. To account for the scroll bars, call the GetSystemMetrics function with SM_CXVSCROLL or SM_CYHSCROLL.

So, the steps are:

1. `GetClientRect()` to get your minimum size client area.
2. `AdjustWindowRectEx()` to convert the client size to window size based on your window styles.
3. If needed, apply additional  adjustments to account for scroll bars (`GetSystemMetrics()` with `SM_CXVSCROLL` and/or `SM_CYHSCROLL`).

Comment: Thanks, That does the trick!  Sure make my head hurt because adding a vertical scroll bar could cause a horizontal scroll bar to be needed.